# OpenVPN Install: Can't access to Client UI page

Tags: openvpn

After installing open vpn successfully, i tested by accessing to Client UI but it said ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Is there any ways to fix it?
@Information: I'm running CentOS 7 on Amazon EC2 instance. 
I turned off selinux and checked if openvpn is running or not.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-48 tmp]# netstat -ntlp | grep 'openvpn'
```

tcp        0      0 10.0.7.48:443           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2023/openvpn-openss

Comment: did you check the firewall on CentOS and Amazon Security Group ?. Please ensure that you can telnet from your client to the Public IP of the EC2 instance, Port 443.

Comment: @SummerNguyen: Hello SummerNguyen, seems like you're from Vietnam, right? :) Yep, basically firewalld on Centos7 (AWS EC2) don't have firewalld by default and i also checked that too. About the AWS's security group, i opened all the port (inbound and outbout) because this is just for testing, not production.

Comment: Yes, I'm from Vietnam. I think you are too :).  For more information, I think you should give more screenshots ,log file  about error, configurations.

Comment: @SummerNguyen: Exactly :D But now i'm working in Japan ^^ 
So i followed this tutorial on vultr, seems like there was something wrong with it. 
There was no log files related to vpn under /var/log/syslog.
if you have AWS account, could you please give it a try?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have AWS Account :( Can you take a screenshot about how to configure, about the Web Page. That's easier for us. Btw, can you give me the tutorial on vultr.

Comment: Ah of course, here's the tutorial: https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-openvpn-on-centos-7
Installing is just the first step and i didn't manage to configure anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36257/discussion-between-the-one-and-summer-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

After manual installing the on the OPENVPN on CentOS7, I Found that there is the due to mismatch in IP configuration.

Please reinit openvpn configuration as follow :

/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init

Please answer the questions by the script.

```
Note from this : lease specify the network interface and IP address to be
used by the Admin Web UI:
(1) all interfaces: 0.0.0.0
(2) enp0s3: 10.0.2.15
(3) enp0s8: 192.168.56.101
Please enter the option number from the list above (1-3).
 Press Enter for default [2]: 1
```

Ensure press 1, to let OpenVPN listen on all interfaces. Due to the problem that Amazon EC2 use NAT in which there are only private IP on Servers.

Hope this help.